# Is it possible to make a v-autocomplete component in Vuetify 3 responsive in height?

Tags: css, typescript, vue.js, responsive, vuetifyjs3

In my company, they ask me to create an autocomplete component using v-autocomplete. I have two resolutions, 1920x1080 and 1280x720. The height of the autocomplete is defined for both 1920 and 1280, but it is not responsive between these two resolutions. I need to achieve this, but the heights in Vuetify are fixed and I can only switch between heights using the density property, which is not what I need. How can I achieve that responsiveness between these two resolutions?

I tried to make it responsive using clamp() in CSS, but I have to change each of the components that affect the height within the v-autocomplete, although it doesn't seem like the best idea to me.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head but it's _probably_ possible to do what you want by modifying different Vuetify SASS variables, but regardless, overriding styles with your own CSS is **always** possible. CSS styling is never "fixed".  Just inspect the DOM to figure out what selectors are needed for the elements you're targetting, then it's just a matter of applying the correct CSS properties and values, probably `height` or similar.  For responsive CSS you can use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to apply different values for different resolutions.